# Using GMail with a custom domain

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-workspace-for-business

I know this can done and I know it can be free as well. But I would like to know the exact procedure step by step how to activate this if you own a domain, but you don't have any web facing web server (I've heard you have to put some file somewhere for google to check to activate domain or something).

### Clarification

I want Google to handle my custom domain mail. Not like forwarding existing mails to Google. That's not what I'd like to know here. I would actually like Google to serve my emails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you want is their [mail hosting service](http://www.ehow.com/how_4788558_use-gmail-domain-name.html). You basically setup the domain MX records through google, but you'll need to point your domain to google's name servers. The link explains the process.

Comment: I actually followed this step-by-step guide and got it working YAY!

Comment: It appears this is now a premium feature. $$$$

Answer (score 5):

You'll find all the help you need for [Google Apps here](http://www.google.com/support/a/), with [sign up details here](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=53926) and information on [verification here](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/topic.py?hl=en&topic=9196), which includes the option of using a DNS record instead of a web page.

Answer (score -1):

If you are asking about sending and receiving emails from you GMail account using an address in another domain (e.g. *yourname@example.com*), you need to:

1. Create the address in the domain and configure it to forward to the GMail account. Most registrars offer several forwarded addresses for free that you can set in the domain control panel.
2. Associate the address with your GMail account (*Settings > Accounts and Import > Send mail from another address*).
3. Confirm the address (since you have the address forwarded to GMail you'll receive the confirmation email in the same account).
4. Optionally make the address the default one, so all your email will appear to be send from *yourname@example.com*.

Comment: I clarified my question which makes your answer invalid. Thanks for the input anyway. BTW: with existing email accounts you can also use POP if you can. Better than forwarding...