# Google allows login, but not access to Gmail or anything else

Tags: gmail

I'm confused why an old email account I have, with my own custom domain is able to login into Google, but yet not have any of the services, like Gmail.

Here's my experience:

[image]

I'm not even sure how to contact Google for help on this, as I want to switch this email account to use Google Apps as well.  But I can't get to any of its settings, yet Google somehow still recognizes it.  But then restricts Gmail for it.

Anyone experience this?
How can I get this sorted out?

Comment: Your issue may be covered by this [question](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/8763/55520). Make sure your MX records are set properly through your domain provider or host.

Comment: Presumably you have accessed Gmail using this domain at some point in the past?

Comment: I must have, but 2008 is a long time ago and don't quite remember the details.

Comment: I'm not sure how MX records are preventing Gmail from letting me access it through the web.  But will look into it.

Comment: My VPS at Linode already has MX records setup for use with Google Apps.  Still though, this email account is not on Google Apps and preventing Gmail access through the web shouldn't be affected by this.  So it's still strange.